# GET Method is going to the right page but stills runs through POST method and has the POST in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm

I have a POST method that returns me to my summary page that looks like this

```
    public ActionResult SpecialOrderSelection(ItemViewModel model)
        {  
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                JobOrder jobOrder = db.JobOrders.Find(model.Id);
                if (jobOrder == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                ViewBag.JobOrderID = jobOrder.ID;
               
            }
            return SpecialOrderSummary(model);
            
        }
```

And here is my Summary GET method

```
  public ActionResult SpecialOrderSummary(ItemViewModel model)
        {
            return View("SpecialOrderSummary", model);
        }
```

It sends me to my SpecialOrderSummary View Page, however the URL still displays as what my POST method is and not my GET. Also on every refresh it goes to the post first.

Why is this?

Comment: I think you are looking for `RedirectToAction`. Maybe you should take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020202/passing-a-model-object-to-a-redirecttoaction-without-polluting-the-url

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, because mvc runs like this.

You should use redirect,

```
  public ActionResult SpecialOrderSelection(ItemViewModel model)
    {  
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            JobOrder jobOrder = db.JobOrders.Find(model.Id);
            if (jobOrder == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.JobOrderID = jobOrder.ID;
           
        }
        return Redirect("SpecialOrderSummary?(your model serialize)");;
        
    }
```